# Reason for Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, operating-system, segmentation-fault, clone, system-calls

I have written a program using clone() system call having CLONE_VM and CLONE_FILES set.
I am not able to understand why the output is showing Segmentation Fault. Can somebody please correct my code and tell me the reason for the same.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<sched.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int variable, fd;

int do_something() {  
    //   sleep(100);  
    variable = 42;  
    close(fd);  
    _exit(0);  
}  

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {  
   void **child_stack;  
   char tempch;  

   variable = 9;  
   fd = open("test.file", O_RDONLY);  
   child_stack = (void **) malloc(16384);  
   printf("The variable was %d\n", variable);  

   clone(do_something, child_stack, CLONE_VM|CLONE_FILES, NULL);  
//   sleep(100);  

   printf("The variable is now %d\n", variable);  
   if (read(fd, &tempch, 1) < 1) {  
      perror("File Read Error");  
      exit(1);  
   }  
   printf("We could read from the file\n");  
   return 0;  
}
```

Comment: Have you verified that `malloc` doesn't return NULL?

Comment: I doubt it's your problem, but `do_something` should take a `void*` argument. I don't belive it's required, but it's still good style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to know which direction stack grows on your processor, and you need to know which end of the stack you must pass to clone().

From `man clone`:

```
Stacks grow downwards on all processors that run Linux (except the
HP PA processors), so child_stack usually points to the topmost
address of the memory space set up for the child stack.
```

You are *not* passing the topmost address, you are passing the bottommost address, and you are not (I am guessing) on HP-PA.

Fix:

```
   child_stack = (void **) malloc(16384) + 16384 / sizeof(*child_stack);
```

P.S. I am *astonished* by the number of *obviously* wrong non-answers here.

- No, close on invalid file descriptor
  does *not* crash on any UNIX and
  Linux system in existence.
- No, `void*` vs. `void**` has nothing at all to do with the problem.
- No, you *don't* need to take an address of do_something, the compiler will do that automatically for you.

And finally, yes: calling `close`, `_exit`, or any other libc routine in the `clone()d` thread is *potentially* unsafe, although it does not cause the problem here.

Answer (score -2):

The way to fix is to have the child stack actually on the stack .. i.e.

> char child_stack [16384];

I suspect that stack pointer can't point to data segment or sth like that...

And even then.. it works with -g .. but crashes with -O !!!

Comment: Why can't we use dynamic memory allocation ?

Comment: This is a completely bogus answer.